# Visual Studio 2022 - Custom controls do not render in designer when in Debug mode

Tags: visual-studio, wpf-controls

Visual Studio 2022, the latest build.  I have an extensive WPF/VB.Net solution that includes custom/user controls.  When I'm designing/editing the solution in Debug mode, my User Controls do not render.  Instead, they get these blue "info" circles next to them.  When I switch to Release mode they render properly (sometimes).  I usually have to change the configuration to x86 or something like that and rebuild it to get it to show.  I never had this problem in Visual Studio 2017.

Problem - Debug screenshot

[image: Problem - Debug screenshot]

Problem - Debug Screenshot 2

[image: Problem - Debug Screenshot 2]

Working - Release mode

[image: Working - Release mode]

Working - Release mode screenshot

[image: Working - Release mode screenshot]

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Nope, just keep switching to release mode.

Comment: Okay, sadly it is very inconvenient. I hope this bug get fixed soon

Comment: I created a post on the Visual Studio Community Forum, maybe it will help:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XAML-Designer-does-not-load-usercontrols/10363533